# Best way to handle asyncronous events in flutter redux

Tags: redux, flutter, flutter-redux

While starting to build an app using flutter and redux I came across the following issue: What's the best way to handle a network request or any asynchronous action?

The context: 
Make an asynchronous call to get a string from the server side (In my case just a Future.delayed) when the request finishes update the state and see the change in the view.

First Approach:

Create a middlewareClass that has an async call function that will wait for the asynchronous event to finish after it finishes call NextDispacther with a new action that will be treated in the reducers

```
 class UserTypeMiddleware extends MiddlewareClass<AppState> {

      @override
      void call(Store<AppState> store, action, NextDispatcher next) async{
        if (action is GetTitleAction) {
          String title = await Future<String>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
            return "This is a title ";
          });
          next(UpdateTitleAction(title));
        } else {
          next(action);
        }
      }

    }
```

Second approach:

Create a typedMiddleware that does kind of the same thing but it dispatches the action via store.dispatch

```
TypedMiddleware<AppState, GetTitleAction> userTypeMiddleware() =>
    TypedMiddleware<AppState, GetTitleAction>(_getTitle);

Future _getTitle(Store<AppState> store, GetTitleAction action, NextDispatcher next) async {
  String title = await Future<String>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
    return "Flow.me este o aplicatie care va permite sa inchiriati un scooter ";
  });
  store.dispatch(UpdateTitleAction(title));
  next(action);
}
```

Third approach:

Use redux_thunk

```
ThunkAction<AppState> updateTitleAction = (Store<AppState> store) async {
  String title = await Future<String>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
    return "Flow.me este o aplicatie care va permite sa inchiriati un scooter ";
  });

  store.dispatch(UpdateTitleAction(title));
};
```

From my point of view I would rather deal with the logic of handling server request in the middleware and not in an action - just for the sake of consistency - middlewares being at the same level as a reducer, for handling logic.

Does it break the redux idea in any way if I am calling NextDispatcher in the middleware with a delay from the async request? Could this represent a problem?

Comment: Or you could use https://pub.dev/packages/async_redux

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle a network request or an asynchronous action is to create middleware for it, do never handle asynchronous action inside reducer (it's a redux anti-pattern, reducer should be pure functions), or you can use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/brianegan/redux_thunk).